# How npm start runs a server on port 8000

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I recently used a angular-seed folder from github for angular application development. In some previous angularjs tutorial there was a script folder and a server.js file in the angular-seed folder which had all the configuration for running the node server. So how does npm now just start running a node server and where is all the configuration of that node server?

Comment: It's in `package.json` file. See: https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/package.json

Comment: I came here searching for a non-angular solution (Next.js which is basically React) and found it solution in [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60451410/5369706). 

Using Next.js, at least for me, ports aren't defined in the `package.json` file;  `npm run dev -- --port ####` let me specify the port.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you will look at `package.json` file.

you will see something like this

```
 "start": "http-server -a localhost -p 8000"
```

This tells start a `http-server` at address of `localhost` on port `8000`

[http-server](https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server) is a node-module.

**Update:-** Including comment by @Usman, ideally it should be present in your `package.json` but if it's not present you can include it in `scripts` section.

Comment: I couldn't find this in my package.json, however adding this under the "scripts": {} section worked for me.

Comment: @Usman Ideally it should be there in your `package.json`, but if not there you can always add it. Updated the answer, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: you just start some http server, but not react-scripts. PORT=3001 react-scripts start solves the problem

Comment: I think in newer versions of npm it's located in "launch.json".

Answer (score 145):

We have a react application and our development machines are both mac and pc.  The start command doesn't work for PC so here is how we got around it:

```
"start": "PORT=3001 react-scripts start",
"start-pc": "set PORT=3001&& react-scripts start",
```

***On my mac:***

```
npm start
```

***On my pc:***

```
 npm run start-pc
```

Comment: This really saved my day! I was looking for a correct to start node on port different from 3000 for Express. Thanks a lot!. By the way, start command does work on PC. It looks like this in my config `"start": "set PORT=3001 && node ./bin/www"`

Comment: Yes, I mistyped.  Start does work on PC, but the syntax for setting the port is different than Mac/Linux.  That's why I have 2 "start" commands.  one is "start" for mac, and one is "start-pc" for my pc.

Comment: Note that this answer is only valid when using react-scripts from create-react-app. For http-server and webpack-dev-server you need to use the `-p` or `--port` flags instead.

Answer (score 139):

To start the port correctly in your desired port use:

```
npm start -- --port 8000
```

Comment: This is exactly what I came here searching for. I am using Next.js (React) and can now run the development server on a given port; `npm run dev -- --port 8000` worked like a charm.

Comment: `Something is already running on port 3000` does not work neither

Comment: This did not work for me. Module automatically starts on 3000.

Comment: Why is there an extra `--`?

Comment: On the two extra `--` there is a very good answer in this thread @AmirHeshmati https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046885/what-does-do-when-running-an-npm-command

Comment: If this doesn't work for you (as it did not work for me), try the solution suggested below, namely:  PORT 8000 npm start

Comment: This command works for me.

Comment: Note that this answer annoyingly will not work when using react-scripts from create-react-app to start your local environment. In that case you have to specify the desired port in the PORT env variable as others have suggested in this comment thread.

Answer (score 115):

To change the port

```
npm start --port 8000
```

Comment: This didn't work but this did
`npm start -- --port 8000`

Answer (score 81):

You can change the port in the console by running the following on *Windows*:

```
SET PORT=8000
```

For *Mac*, *Linux* or *Windows WSL* use the following:

```
export PORT=8000
```

The *export* sets the environment variable for the current shell and all child processes like *npm* that might use it.

If you want the environment variable to be set just for the *npm* process, precede the command with the environment variable like this (on *Mac* and *Linux* and *Windows WSL*):

```
PORT=8000 npm run start
```

Comment: This is much simpler for temporarily testing things out. Thanks!

Comment: I just specify it as part of the start command when I'm already running other projects on 'default' ports.  `PORT=<port #> npm start`

Comment: This is what worked for me perfectly

Answer (score 9):

```
npm run dev -- --port 3001
```

npm run on another port in cmd

Answer (score 6):

change `"start": "react-scripts start",` to `"start": "set PORT=3001 && react-scripts start",`

Answer (score 6):

**Or simply in the terminal**

```
set port=5500 && npm start
```

Answer (score 2):

```
npm start -- --port "port number"
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution which will work on every machine, let it be MAC, Window, Linux or  any other, just specify the port where you want to run. In your package.json do this :

```
 "start": "export PORT=3001 && react-scripts start "
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm run start -- -p 8000
```

**8000 is port number you can change your port number**

Answer (score 0):

`npm start --port 8000` does not work. You should write command like this.

```
ng serve --port 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

(For those still suffering despite trying all the answers.)

Here is a quick fix that should not be used in production!

Just forward the source port to the target one that you need. Open another shell and tap this command:

```
socat tcp-listen:8000,reuseaddr,fork tcp:192.168.1.48:3000
```

In this example; 3000 is the port of the server and 8000 the port you want to forward to (or receive from to be precise)

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

or simply call: (if you don't want to set up anything)

PORT=8000 npm start

Comment: It's correct that you can use `PORT=8000 npm start` but what do you mean by "(if you don't want to set up anything)". AFAIK this statement is not correct.