# Select environment when build SSR app - Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, server-side-rendering

Usually, when I build simple SPAs, I use `--c` flag to select proper environment and put configs to `angular.json` inside `configurations` dict, that lives in `build` dict like so:

```
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "staging": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "aot": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

How can I run SSR build with proper environment, when I use command `npm run build:ssr`?

I tried same scheme `npm run build:ssr --c staging`, but got error `Unknown option: 'staging'`

Comment: I think you're providing the c argument to npm instead of `build:ssr`. Can you try `npm run build:ssr -- --c staging`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046885/what-does-do-when-running-an-npm-command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't build ssr with a specific environment using `npm run build:ssr` command. Because this command builds with `production` environment by default as should be stated in the `angular.json` config.

To do so, you have to change your build scripts in the `package.json`.

```
"build:ssr": "ng build && ng run my-app:server",
"build:staging:ssr": "ng build --configuration=staging && ng run my-app:server:staging",
```

Now run `npm run build:staging:ssr`

Answer (score 0):

I think you typed the wrong command. You can run the command below:

```
 ng build -c staging
```

Or you can create the npm script in your  `package.json`:

```
  "scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
"build:ssr": "ng build -c staging",
```

} and run the command below:

```
npm run build:ssr
```