# Difference between double dash with no argument (--) vs double dash with arguments (eg: --no-watch)

Tags: angular, npm, arguments, command

Example: The following command is executed when I am trying to execute unit tests of an Angular app:
`npm run test -- --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI`

I understood that the double dash (--) is needed to pass arguments into the npm script.
but I don't understand what is the first '--' trying to do? because it does not have any argument behind it, does not like `--no-watch` or `--browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI`

the command example from: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: The npm v6.x [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-run-script#description) provide the following description: _"As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option `--` is used by `getopt` to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script"_. Essentially, the special `--` option demarcates the end of any option(s) belonging to the npm run command itself (e.g. `--silent`), and the beginning of the argument(s) that are to be passed to the end of the npm script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does -- do when running an npm command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046885/what-does-do-when-running-an-npm-command)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is how npm parses the command. In your example:

`npm run test -- --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI`

The `--` tells npm that any following arguments are for the `test` script, and not npm. Take this example:
`npm run test --workspace=a -- --no-watch --browsers=ChromeHeadlessCI`

Workspaces are functionality of npm, not the test script.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script