# npm run dev --host network: not exposed

Tags: linux, npm, server, sveltekit, npm-run

I want to expose my svelte app on LAN using the `npm run dev --host` command but it shows:

```
> frontend@0.0.1 dev
> svelte-kit dev


  SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.295

  local:   http://localhost:3000
  network: not exposed

  Use --host to expose server to other devices on this network
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You have to add `--` before the actual flag:

```sh
npm run dev -- --host
```

And it should output:

```
> project@0.0.1 dev
> svelte-kit dev "--host"


  SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.316

  local:   http://localhost:3000
  network: http://***.***.**.**:3000

  Note that all files in the following directories will be accessible to anyone on your network: src/lib, src/routes, .svelte-kit, src, node_modules
```

Comment: For homestead, have to look at Homestead.yaml and find the right ip. Then you go npm run dev -- --host={The IP From Homestead.yaml}

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining why you need to add '--' . For anyone else who arrives here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43046885/what-does-do-when-running-an-npm-command

Answer (score 10):

If you use **vite** in the *package.json* file, do this on the *dev* line:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --host --port 8888",
   .....  what ever else was here.....
  },
```

if you use **sirv**, try this in the *package.json* :

```json
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear --host 0.0.0.0",
```

If you want a different port try this:

```json
    "start": "sirv public --no-clear --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8888",
```

Comment: thanks for the help, Adding the line "vite --host --port 8888" in the package.json file actually did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

In vite Two Methods as follows:

Method 1: Manually while running the app by typing this on the terminal

```
npm run dev -- --host
```

Method 2: Automatically By replacing the "dev" property line in package.json in the "scripts" object as follows:

```
"dev": "vite --host --port [PORT NO. YOU WANT TO USE]",
```

And when you run "npm run dev", it shows the network host address

Answer (score 3):

You can add  this to your vite.config.js

```
server: {
        host: true
      }
```