# sudo npm run start Admin permissions error?

Tags: reactjs, npm, permissions, react-scripts

I am trying to run react application as sudo on port 443 but it is throwing permissions error as follows. I tried running the react script with root privileges too but get the same error.

Command used is

> sudo npm run start

Error

> ? Admin permissions are required to run a server on a port below 1024. Probably:
> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Frameworks/Google Chrome Framework.framework/Versions/91.0.4472.114/Helpers/Google Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper --type=utility --utility-sub-type=network.mojom.NetworkService --field-trial-handle=1718379636,2199499938256335430,15968884667410910440,131072 --enable-features=BlockInsecurePrivateNetworkRequests,CookieSameSiteConsidersRedirectChain,CriticalClientHint,CrossOriginEmbedderPolicyCredentialless,CrossOriginIsolated,CrossOriginOpenerPolicyAccessReporting,CrossOriginOpenerPolicyReporting,DocumentPolicyNegotiation,EnableNewCanvas2DAPI,ExperimentalContentSecurityPolicyFeatures,FeaturePolicyForClientHints,LangClientHintHeader,OriginIsolationHeader,OriginPolicy,SchemefulSameSite,UserAgentClientHint --lang=en-US --service-sandbox-type=network --enable-experimental-web-platform-features --metrics-client-id=22a9279b-1648-45cf-a03c-0ce68df69ad5 --shared-files --seatbelt-client=27 (pid 887)
> in /
> Would you like to run the app on another port instead? (Y/n)

I checked port 443 and it is available to listen. I also wrote a script to listen on port 443 on localhost and it is able to bind on this port as a sudo user. No luck with the react app though.

I was able to run react app earlier in the same laptop but something changed and I don't know what. The error is anyway about permissions but I ruled out this possibility.

I feel it has something to do with Google Chrome Helper which react-scripts is trying to run without Admin Privilege.

Also, it could be some other package I installed which may have caused the issue.

I am at a loss here and am not sure how to debug it further. Googling the problem didn't help either. Any help to debug or fix the issue is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Mac OS Big Sur - version 11.4
npm version 7.18.1

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get around this issue, by using this `package.json` command:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start-https": "sudo PORT=443 HTTPS=true react-scripts start"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The only way I found it to work (especially when you install `node` and `npm` using `nvm`) is to call `react-scripts` directly:

```
sudo node ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
```

This assumes you are in the project / repository directory containing `.node_modules`. Nevertheless, it is different question whether its correct to `npm start` with `sudo`. I was just experimenting to run the dev server on port 80 and it was giving error

```
Admin permissions are required to run a server on a port below 1024.
```

And I was unable to fix it with various solutions specified on these links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21215059/cant-use-nvm-from-root-or-sudo), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472755/sudo-npm-command-not-found), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750253/how-npm-start-runs-a-server-on-port-8000), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078875/13782227). From these links I mostly tried configuration related solutions as I did not wanted to reinstall node (without `nvm`).

Answer (score 3):

I met the same issue, and solved by downgrading the node version from 16 to 14, don't know why but works.