# Running a docker container on localhost not working

Tags: javascript, python, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have created a Dockerfile image with an easy react app boilerplate result of `npx create-react-app my-app`

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 4000
CMD "npm" "start
```

Everything worked fine and created the image, started the container, no errors but cannot open on localhost, does anybody know what could be the problem ?

I have used `docker run -p 4000:4000 -it react-repo` to start the container.

Comment: Could you provide the complete `docker run`  command used. I believe it might be a problem of exposed ports.

Comment: @usuario  `docker run -p 4000:4000 -it react-repo`

Comment: Have you configured the app to listen on port 4000? Looks like the the default is port 3000.

Comment: Have you changed [`package.json`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24750341/11647025) to expose port 4000?

Comment: @ogdenkev hmmm that could be the issue, but why if I'm exposing another port, is not loading the exposed port in Dockerfile ?

Comment: The `EXPOSE` instruction and `docker run -p 4000:4000` simply tell the docker daemon to expose a port from the container to the host. It does not ensure that anything inside the container is listening on that port. To do that, you have to set up your app to listen on port 4000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample Docker file for below express.js app.

```js
const express = require('express');

const PORT = 8080;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

To Run,

```
# docker run -p <host-port>:<container-port> imageName
docker run -p 8080:8080 imageName
```

Comment: already tried that and is the same result, not oppening in localhost

Comment: which port is your app listening to?

Comment: should be the default 3000 ...

Comment: either reconfigure your exposed port to ```4000``` or change it to ```3000``` in Dockerfile. This could help

Comment: add please also the run command in your answer .

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm also facing the same issue with Docker on M1