# How to choose the port used in the project with Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, containers

I'm studying docker, so I got a default react app and I'm trying to implement docker in it, and everything worked fine when I ran on the default port (3000) but when I try to change ports to 8000, firefox gives me an error (connection was reset). I would like to know what is happening for this error to happen.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:13-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8001
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    app:
        container_name: docker
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        volumes:
            - '.:/app'
            - '/app/node_modules'
        ports:
            - '8000:8000'
        environment:
            - NODE_ENV=development
```

Comment: You changed the docker side to forward port 8000 on the host to 8000 in the container,  but you haven't configured NPM to listen on port 8000 in the container, so it's still using its default .  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750253/how-npm-start-runs-a-server-on-port-8000/44473239

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How npm start runs a server on port 8000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750253/how-npm-start-runs-a-server-on-port-8000)

Comment: Thank you!! so whenever i want should i change the port in package.json? there is no way to choose port by docker?

Comment: That link I pasted sad you can use `PORT` environment variable, which you can set in docker-compose right next to NODE_ENV

Answer (score 0):

add to your package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=8000 react-scripts start",
  },
```