# How to run the server when the files are in different folders?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

My project is split into 2 folders client and server

How can I run the script through npm start to run both the backend and the frontend at the same time

Screenshot given below:
[Two Folders in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU8Fk.png)

[Client Folder Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afT9f.png)

[Server Folder Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54Fzf.png)

Please help me how to run the complete project

Comment: How do you run your frontend? Usually a frontend consists of static files. Sometimes a frontend has its own webserver. Sometimes the backend generates the frontend.

Comment: I don't know how to run it. It doesn't work by npm start

Comment: Again: Usually you don't run a frontend. It consists of static files. Your question is unclear and lacking important details. You should ask the person who gave you this project.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to run it on different ports. For example, run the client on port 3000 and the server on port 3001.

[you can look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24750253/how-npm-start-runs-a-server-on-port-8000)